# Display img in row bootstrap table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display two images next to each other inside a bootstrap table, any ideas?

Heres the code,

```
   <tr>
       <th scope="row">7</th>
       <td></td>
       <td>
            <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
        </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display images next to each others you can use `div`instead of `table`, because it will be the best practice.

In Bootstrap, every `row` is divided into `12` columns. You can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) for your clarification about grid system of Bootstrap. You can use any combination to set your images.

```
6 + 6 = 12
4 + 4 + 4 = 12
3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 12
-
-
etc
```

If we take 4 + 4 + 4 = 12 this combination for example. We will be able to set images in any two div. Code will be like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
       <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">

   </div>

</div>
```

If you want to use table, then firstly read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp) article. Then code will be like the below:

```
<table>
   <th scope="row">7</th>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
       </td>
       <td>
          <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: This is the best answer to be, because it shows the "Bootstrap way". By using its grid system, you make sure you can easily control the UI behaviour on screens of different sizes.

Comment: @Mr. Perfectionist: well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try this simple code for responsive bootstrap table, let me know

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
       <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="image1.jpg"></td>   
    <td><img src="image2.jpg"></td>       
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the css

`img{
    display:inline-block;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
   <th scope="row">7</th>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
 <img class="img" src="example.jpg" alt="">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
<tr> 
    <th scope="row">7</th>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap"> <!--div as flexbox with content in a row without wrap-->
            <div class="img img-responsive"> <!--responsive img inside div-->
                <img class="img img-fluid" src="example.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img img-responsive"> <!--responsive img inside div-->
                    <img class="img img-fluid" src="example.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```